# ¿Cómo sacar porcentaje (cuota) de venta por marca con respecto al total por vendedor en SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Tengo una taba con las columnas `Marca`, `Vendedor` y `Precio`, esta última no relevante en este caso. Mi problema es que  **necesito sacar un porcentaje de venta de cada marca con respecto al total por vendedor**, es decir, si el vendedor ha vendido 1000 unidades de las cuales 218 han sido Samsung, por ejemplo, 121 Huawei, etc, quiero que me aparezca en una columna nueva (columna exportable a Excel, no solo de presentación visual) el resultado de 21,8% y 12,1% respectivamente. No tengo problema en calcular el porcentaje (aunque seguro que habrá alguna función de SQLite que lo haga más fácil)

El problema estriba en cómo poner la relación en un `SELECT`. He estado leyendo sobre `Join` pero creo que lo que necesito es hacer *selects* anidados sobre la misma base de datos. Y no encuentro la información adecuada para ello.

[image: imagen descriptiva]
Si tengo:

```
SELECT
   marca,
   vendedor,
   SUM(1),
   SUM(Precio),
FROM
   moviles 
GROUP BY
   marca,
   vendedor
```

Ese `SUM(1)` hace un recuento de unidades vendidas por marca si hago un `GROUP BY marca, vendedor` y por vendedor si hago un `GROUP BY vendedor`.

Comment: Podrias leer [ask]? tu pregunta esta desordenada y es dificil ayudarte asi. Muestra la estructura de las tablas, las relaciones, el query de una forma clara, y tambien que resultado obtuviste hasta ahora y cual queres obtener para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: has indagado sobre la funcion `AVG` ?

Comment: Hola! Acabo de editar y aceptar la edición sugerida. Soy nuevo por aquí, tened algo de paciencia.
srJJ, la función AVG calcula la media, no es mi caso. Realmente el problema no está en el cálculo sino en como crear el SELECT correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi tienes resuelto el problema, solo tienes que combinar los totales por vendedor con los totales por vendedor / marca.

```
SELECT  m.vendedor, 
    m.marca, 
    (cast(COUNT(1) AS float / v.TotalVendedor) * 100 AS 'Porcentaje'
    FROM moviles AS m
    INNER JOIN (SELECT vendedor,
                       cast(COUNT(1) AS float AS 'TotalVendedor'
                       FROM moviles
                       GROUP BY vendedor
        ) AS v
        ON m.vendedor = v.vendedor
    GROUP BY 
        m.vendedor,
        m.marca
```

La combinación de ambas consultas se hace mediante subconsultas encerradas por `()`, en este caso la combinamos con un `INNER JOIN`. Reemplaze tu  `SUM(1)` por un `COUNT(1)` por que se entiende mejor lo que se está haciendo aunque en este caso el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho, creo que funciona. No puedo meterle un `WHERE` después de `AS m`? por ejemplo: `FROM moviles AS m WHERE m.Precio = 200` o `FROM moviles  WHERE m.Precio = 200 AS m`. Esto me da error y es absolutamente necesario. Sin embargo, sí me deja ponerlo dentro del `Inner Join`.

Comment: No el `WHERE` siempre  luego de los `FROM` y `JOINS`, en este ejemplo es justo antes del `GROUP BY`

Comment: Estupendo @Patricio Moracho Funciona todo a la perfección excepto que me da porcentaje = 0 dado que `COUNT(1) / v.TotalVendedor` lo entiende como 0 en lugar de 0,45 por ejemplo. He probado  con ´*100.0´ pero no funciona. Cómo podría hacer para que detecte los decimales?

Comment: Me contesto a mí mismo. Ya lo solucioné. Simplemente cambié esto:
`(COUNT(1) / v.TotalVendedor)` por esto 
`(cast(COUNT(1) AS float) / cast(v.TotalVendedor AS float))`
Muchas gracias por todo. Pincharé en mejor solución.

Comment: @Toni, si, efectivamente corresponde hacer un `cast`  a `float`, también podría resolverse así `COUNT(1.0)`